# How can I verify the access_token from next-auth on a express node.js server?

Tags: node.js, validation, next.js, jwt

I am still learning the way of Next.js and I got some problems when working with tokens..

The problem is that, as far I know, I can use the access_token given by a provider (example: Google) as a token for verification on a custom backend (In ths case, express node.js).
I get the token to my backend but I don't know how to verify the authenticity of said token.
all is handled inside the headers of the fetch function, like this:

const verified = jwt.verify(token, secret_key)

```
headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        authorization: `bearer ${session.user.access_token}`,
        email: session.user.email
      }
```

On the server I tried to do this inside a middleware before prooceding:

```
const verified = jwt.verify(token, secret_key)
```

but all I get in return is "jwt malformed" as an error.
I tried removing the word "bearer" but got the same result. I don't know if this is the correct token I should send or how I should validate. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!
I don't mind if I get other replies to work around this problem. Like creating the JWT token from the express server and giving it to the callback of next-auth (I haven't tried)

After trying to verify I tried send different data, such as the next-auth token that is saved on the cookies section of the browser, but still the same result...

Answer (score 0):

You can use decode imported from 'next-auth/jwt' to verify token

Comment: What I wanted to try is send this token to a custom backend (node.js) and decode it over there. This question was made weeks ago and I found out that the tokens made by next.js can only be used on the Next.js app/server itself, so, If I want to manage sessions and tokens, I should send a request on SignIn to my custom backend (or on the JWT function) and replace/make a new token from this custom backend and send it back to the front-end/client and work around it (like I wanted)...
not so easy but no so hard. I haven't tried yet...

Comment: as the title u set, i see that u want to verify token from next-auth on nodejs server, so u can install next-auth package on nodejs server and use function 'decode' import from 'next-auth/jwt' to decode that token

Comment: I didn't even think about that, I will try later. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I forgot to reply this, but anyways, I tried what nguyen told me to do, but it didn't work.

The best approach for this problem was, install the "jsonwebtoken" library/package on my next.js project, inside the API code I call the user session along the token, I decoded it and finally I encoded the payload/session and sent it to my node.js backend (or anywhere where I desire). Doing this is pretty secure since the user/client is never able to see anything privated.
I could provide a code, but the steps should be enough for now